# Sorting input integers directly to a list

Tags: python

To sort a series of numbers from the console, it is first appended into an `myList` and this `myList` is sorted using `myList.sort()`

```
n = int(input())
count = 0
myList = []

while count < n:
    i = int(input())
    myList.append(i)
    count += 1
    
myList.sort()
print(myList)
```

Is there a way in which as it gets added to the list it is directly and automatically placed in the correct order/index? I want to get rid of the `sort()` function and the unsorted `myList`, if possible.

Comment: Yes, but is probably going to be more expensive (in terms of operations) that your current solution. If you keep using a list

Comment: why would it be more expensive? If they implement a heap, they could have a nice sorted array pretty cheap.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh as you said if they implement a heap.

Comment: Have a look at [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bisect.insort` to insert into an already sorted list.

```
>>> from bisect import insort
>>> l = []
>>> insort(l, 5)
>>> l
[5]
>>> insort(l, 1)
>>> l
[1, 5]
>>> insort(l, 2)
>>> l
[1, 2, 5]
```

edit: If you don't require the list to be sorted after every insertion I'd just sort it once after the loop, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SortedList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) from [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html):

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

n = int(input())
count = 0
myList = SortedList()


while count < n:
    i = int(input())
    myList.add(i)
    count += 1

print(myList)
```

**Output** *(example of a dummy run)*

```
4
5
3
2
1
SortedList([1, 2, 3, 5])
```

It keeps the list sorted and the insertion time is O(logn) (see the documentation on [`.add`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedList.add))

**Note**

SortedContainers is a third-party library, needs to be install by doing:

```
pip install sortedcontainers
```

Answer (score 1):

The `heapq` module is yet another option:

```
from heapq import heappush, nsmallest

def myheap():
    heap=[]
    n=int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        heappush(heap, int(input()))
    return nsmallest(n, heap)
```

Comment: If you read the [heapq documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#basic-examples), it says that this implementation is actually almost equivalent to using `sorted` (without the stable sort and optimizations)

Comment: True, and it is slower, too. But since we don't know the actual use case it seems fair to list all the possibilities